# How to figure the calories in a boxed cake mix if applesauce is used instead of egg and oil?

Tags: calories

How can I calculate calories in a cake if I use applesauce instead of egg and oil? Because on the box it is counted using the egg and oil.

Comment: look up calories for egg, look up calories for oil, look up calories for amount applesauce, add and subtract from the number on the box?

Answer (score 6):

The nice thing about calories is that they are very constant, mixing or combining things does not change the sum of calories.

So in short, calculate the calories you add (the applesauce) and the calories you leave out (eggs, oil). Add and subtract these from what the box says and you're done.

If the box gives calories per unit or serving, you'd first have to calculate the calories for the whole box, then do the adding / substracting step, then, if wanted, divide the results into servings again. (The [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three) comes handy in these cases.)